# Передача параметров в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу функцию, которая будет преобразовывать дату в Unix-time, но никак не приходит в голову способ, по которому я могу передать параметры (день, месяц, год):

```
def UnixTime (day, month, year):
    return int(time.mktime(time.strptime('09-09-2009', '%d-%m-%Y')))
```

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь методом [datetime.timestamp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

```
In [7]: from datetime import datetime as DT

In [8]: DT(2019, 2, 11).timestamp()
Out[8]: 1549839600.0
```